# Add-in for enable undo/redo on forms designer in vb6

Tags: forms, vb6, undo

is there any add-in for enable in visual basic 6 designer the undo/redo buttons like in visual studio .net?

It's very boring when i wrong to resize or to move a component.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i used to work with sizeone of component one. Here reference http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/sizerone8/default.htm?turl=componentonesizerone80.htm